# End of line without continuation problem again. Need to add this to BTC or ETH

Tags: plot, pine-script, tabular, cryptocurrency, technical-indicator

first question here. Just starting to learn PineScript and I just want to add this to my charts. The first error is the usual "end of line without continuation" at line 69 (I tried on that particular line in different ways but with no result), I believe once that's solved there's gonna be another errors related to the use of tabular space right?
If anyone is willing to try to add this to any crypto and tell me what's wrong I would appreciate it.
Here's the actual code (also the original code was in version 4, the change of version affects it?)

Thanks!

```
study(title="El Loco", overlay=true)//, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,
commission_value=0.025, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, default_qty_value=10000,
initial_capital=10000, slippage=0

// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
// useDate = input(true, title=&#39;---------------- Use Date ----------------&#39;, type=input.bool)
// FromMonth = input(defval=7, title=&quot;From Month&quot;, minval=1, maxval=12)
// FromDay = input(defval=25, title=&quot;From Day&quot;, minval=1, maxval=31)
// FromYear = input(defval=2019, title=&quot;From Year&quot;, minval=2017)
// ToMonth = input(defval=1, title=&quot;To Month&quot;, minval=1, maxval=12)
// ToDay = input(defval=1, title=&quot;To Day&quot;, minval=1, maxval=31)
// ToYear = input(defval=9999, title=&quot;To Year&quot;, minval=2017)
// start = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00) // backtest start window
// finish = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59) // backtest finish window
// window() =&gt; // create function &quot;within window of time&quot;
// time &gt;= start and time &lt;= finish ? true : false
// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===

sources = input(defval=close, title="Source")
isHA = input(false, "Use HA Candles", input.bool)
heikenashi_1 = heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
security_1 = security(heikenashi_1, timeframe.period, sources)
src = isHA ? security_1 : sources
// Sampling Period
// Settings for 5min chart, BTCUSDC. For Other coin, change the paremeters
per = input(defval=27, minval=1, title="Sampling Period")

// Range Multiplier
mult = input(defval=1.0, minval=0.1, title="Range Multiplier")

// Smooth Average Range

smoothrng(x, t, m) =>
    wper = t * 2 - 1
    avrng = ema(abs(x - x[1]), t)
    smoothrng = ema(avrng, wper) * m

    smoothrng
smrng = smoothrng(src, per, mult)

// Range Filter

rngfilt(x, r) =>
    rngfilt = x
    rngfilt := x > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? x - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x - r :
     x + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x + r
    rngfilt
filt = rngfilt(src, smrng)

// Filter Direction

upward = 0.0
upward := filt > filt[1] ? nz(upward[1]) + 1 : filt < filt[1] ? 0 : nz(upward[1])
downward = 0.0
downward := filt < filt[1] ? nz(downward[1]) + 1 : filt > filt[1] ? 0 : nz(downward[1])

// Target Bands

hband = filt + smrng
lband = filt - smrng

// Colors

filtcolor = upward > 0 ? color.lime : downward > 0 ? color.red : color.orange
barcolor = src > filt and src > src[1] and upward > 0 ? color.lime :
    src > filt and src < src[1] and upward > 0 ? color.green :
    src < filt and src < src[1] and downward > 0 ? color.red :
    src < filt and src > src[1] and downward > 0 ? color.maroon : color.orange

//filtplot = plot(filt, color=filtcolor, linewidth=3, title="Range Filter")

// Target

hbandplot = plot(hband, color=color.aqua, transp=100, title="High Target")
lbandplot = plot(lband, color=color.fuchsia, transp=100, title="Low Target")

// Fills

//fill(hbandplot, filtplot, color=color.aqua, title="High Target Range")
//fill(lbandplot, filtplot, color=color.fuchsia, title="Low Target Range")

// Bar Color

//barcolor(barcolor)

// Break Outs

longCond = bool(na)
shortCond = bool(na)
longCond := src > filt and src > src[1] and upward > 0 or
    src > filt and src < src[1] and upward > 0
shortCond := src < filt and src < src[1] and downward > 0 or
    src < filt and src > src[1] and downward > 0

CondIni = 0
CondIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : CondIni[1]
longCondition = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1
shortCondition = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1

//Alerts

plotshape(longCondition, title="Buy Signal", text="⁎", textcolor=color.white,
style=shape.labelup, size=size.large, location=location.belowbar, color=color.black, transp=10)
plotshape(shortCondition, title="Sell Signal", text="⁎", textcolor=color.white,
style=shape.labeldown, size=size.large, location=location.abovebar, color=color.black,
transp=10)

//strategy.entry(&quot;Long&quot;, strategy.long, stop = hband, when = window() , comment="Long")
//strategy.entry(&quot;Short&quot;, strategy.short, stop = lband, when = window() , comment="Short")

// strategy.entry(&quot;Long&quot;, strategy.long, when=longCondition and window(), comment="Long")
// strategy.entry(&quot;Short&quot;, strategy.short, when=shortCondition and window(),
comment="Short")

// // === Stop LOSS ===
// useStopLoss = input(false, title=&#39;----- Use Stop Loss / Take profit -----&#39;, type=input.bool)
// sl_inp = input(100, title=&#39;Stop Loss %&#39;, type=input.float, step=0.25) / 100
// tp_inp = input(1.5, title=&#39;Take Profit %&#39;, type=input.float, step=0.25) / 100
// stop_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp)
// take_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_inp)
// stop_level_short = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + sl_inp)
// take_level_short = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - tp_inp)
// // === Stop LOSS ===

// if useStopLoss
// strategy.exit(&quot;Stop Loss/Profit Long&quot;, &quot;Long&quot;, stop=stop_level, limit=take_level)
// strategy.exit(&quot;Stop Loss/Profit Short&quot;, &quot;Short&quot;, stop=stop_level_short,
limit=take_level_short)

// EMA

showEMA = input(false, title="EMA - Enabled")
emaConfig1 = input(21, "EMA 1", input.integer)
emaConfig2 = input(50, "Ema 2", input.integer)
emaConfig3 = input(200, "Ema 3", input.integer)
ema1 = ema(close, emaConfig1)
ema2 = ema(close, emaConfig2)
ema3 = ema(close, emaConfig3)
plot(showEMA ? ema1 : na, title="EMA", color=#FFFF00, linewidth=1)
plot(showEMA ? ema2 : na, title="EMA", color=#FF84D0, linewidth=1)
plot(showEMA ? ema3 : na, title="EMA", color=#9700FF, linewidth=1)

// BB

showBB = input(false, title="BB - Enabled")
length = input(20, minval=1, title="BB - Length")
multBB = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB - StdDev")

basis = sma(close, length)
dev = multBB * stdev(close, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
offset = input(0, "BB - Offset", type = input.integer, minval = -500, maxval = 500)

plot(showBB ? basis : na, "Basis", color=#872323, offset = offset)
p1 = plot(showBB ? upper : na, "Upper", color=color.teal, offset = offset)
p2 = plot(showBB ? lower : na, "Lower", color=color.teal, offset = offset)
fill(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=#198787, transp=95)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the lines in one line only like below

```
//@version=4
study(title="El Loco", overlay=true)//, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,
commission_value=0.025, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, default_qty_value=10000,
initial_capital=10000, slippage=0

// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
// useDate = input(true, title=&#39;---------------- Use Date ----------------&#39;, type=input.bool)
// FromMonth = input(defval=7, title=&quot;From Month&quot;, minval=1, maxval=12)
// FromDay = input(defval=25, title=&quot;From Day&quot;, minval=1, maxval=31)
// FromYear = input(defval=2019, title=&quot;From Year&quot;, minval=2017)
// ToMonth = input(defval=1, title=&quot;To Month&quot;, minval=1, maxval=12)
// ToDay = input(defval=1, title=&quot;To Day&quot;, minval=1, maxval=31)
// ToYear = input(defval=9999, title=&quot;To Year&quot;, minval=2017)
// start = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, 00, 00) // backtest start window
// finish = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, 23, 59) // backtest finish window
// window() =&gt; // create function &quot;within window of time&quot;
// time &gt;= start and time &lt;= finish ? true : false
// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===

sources = input(defval=close, title="Source")
isHA = input(false, "Use HA Candles", input.bool)
heikenashi_1 = heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
security_1 = security(heikenashi_1, timeframe.period, sources)
src = isHA ? security_1 : sources
// Sampling Period
// Settings for 5min chart, BTCUSDC. For Other coin, change the paremeters
per = input(defval=27, minval=1, title="Sampling Period")

// Range Multiplier
mult = input(defval=1.0, minval=0.1, title="Range Multiplier")

// Smooth Average Range

smoothrng(x, t, m) =>
    wper = t * 2 - 1
    avrng = ema(abs(x - x[1]), t)
    smoothrng = ema(avrng, wper) * m

    smoothrng
smrng = smoothrng(src, per, mult)

// Range Filter

rngfilt(x, r) =>
    rngfilt = x
    rngfilt := x > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? x - r < nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x - r :
     x + r > nz(rngfilt[1]) ? nz(rngfilt[1]) : x + r
    rngfilt
filt = rngfilt(src, smrng)

// Filter Direction

upward = 0.0
upward := filt > filt[1] ? nz(upward[1]) + 1 : filt < filt[1] ? 0 : nz(upward[1])
downward = 0.0
downward := filt < filt[1] ? nz(downward[1]) + 1 : filt > filt[1] ? 0 : nz(downward[1])

// Target Bands

hband = filt + smrng
lband = filt - smrng

// Colors

filtcolor = upward > 0 ? color.lime : downward > 0 ? color.red : color.orange
barcolor = src > filt and src > src[1] and upward > 0 ? color.lime :    src > filt and src < src[1] and upward > 0 ? color.green :    src < filt and src < src[1] and downward > 0 ? color.red :    src < filt and src > src[1] and downward > 0 ? color.maroon : color.orange

//filtplot = plot(filt, color=filtcolor, linewidth=3, title="Range Filter")

// Target

hbandplot = plot(hband, color=color.aqua, transp=100, title="High Target")
lbandplot = plot(lband, color=color.fuchsia, transp=100, title="Low Target")

// Fills

//fill(hbandplot, filtplot, color=color.aqua, title="High Target Range")
//fill(lbandplot, filtplot, color=color.fuchsia, title="Low Target Range")

// Bar Color

//barcolor(barcolor)

// Break Outs

longCond = bool(na)
shortCond = bool(na)
longCond := src > filt and src > src[1] and upward > 0 or    src > filt and src < src[1] and upward > 0
shortCond := src < filt and src < src[1] and downward > 0 or    src < filt and src > src[1] and downward > 0

CondIni = 0
CondIni := longCond ? 1 : shortCond ? -1 : CondIni[1]
longCondition = longCond and CondIni[1] == -1
shortCondition = shortCond and CondIni[1] == 1

//Alerts

plotshape(longCondition, title="Buy Signal", text="⁎", textcolor=color.white,style=shape.labelup, size=size.large, location=location.belowbar, color=color.black, transp=10)
plotshape(shortCondition, title="Sell Signal", text="⁎", textcolor=color.white,style=shape.labeldown, size=size.large, location=location.abovebar, color=color.black,transp=10)

//strategy.entry(&quot;Long&quot;, strategy.long, stop = hband, when = window() , comment="Long")
//strategy.entry(&quot;Short&quot;, strategy.short, stop = lband, when = window() , comment="Short")

// strategy.entry(&quot;Long&quot;, strategy.long, when=longCondition and window(), comment="Long")
// strategy.entry(&quot;Short&quot;, strategy.short, when=shortCondition and window(),comment="Short")

// // === Stop LOSS ===
// useStopLoss = input(false, title=&#39;----- Use Stop Loss / Take profit -----&#39;, type=input.bool)
// sl_inp = input(100, title=&#39;Stop Loss %&#39;, type=input.float, step=0.25) / 100
// tp_inp = input(1.5, title=&#39;Take Profit %&#39;, type=input.float, step=0.25) / 100
// stop_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_inp)
// take_level = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_inp)
// stop_level_short = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + sl_inp)
// take_level_short = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - tp_inp)
// // === Stop LOSS ===

// if useStopLoss
// strategy.exit(&quot;Stop Loss/Profit Long&quot;, &quot;Long&quot;, stop=stop_level, limit=take_level)
// strategy.exit(&quot;Stop Loss/Profit Short&quot;, &quot;Short&quot;, stop=stop_level_short,limit=take_level_short)

// EMA

showEMA = input(false, title="EMA - Enabled")
emaConfig1 = input(21, "EMA 1", input.integer)
emaConfig2 = input(50, "Ema 2", input.integer)
emaConfig3 = input(200, "Ema 3", input.integer)
ema1 = ema(close, emaConfig1)
ema2 = ema(close, emaConfig2)
ema3 = ema(close, emaConfig3)
plot(showEMA ? ema1 : na, title="EMA", color=#FFFF00, linewidth=1)
plot(showEMA ? ema2 : na, title="EMA", color=#FF84D0, linewidth=1)
plot(showEMA ? ema3 : na, title="EMA", color=#9700FF, linewidth=1)

// BB

showBB = input(false, title="BB - Enabled")
length = input(20, minval=1, title="BB - Length")
multBB = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB - StdDev")

basis = sma(close, length)
dev = multBB * stdev(close, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
offset = input(0, "BB - Offset", type = input.integer, minval = -500, maxval = 500)

plot(showBB ? basis : na, "Basis", color=#872323, offset = offset)
p1 = plot(showBB ? upper : na, "Upper", color=color.teal, offset = offset)
p2 = plot(showBB ? lower : na, "Lower", color=color.teal, offset = offset)
fill(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=#198787, transp=95)
```